# how to get a distinct list of formatted dates sorted using Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

It makes some years since I studied sql so, I am having trouble getting a
**get a distinct list of formatted dates sorted** using Mysql. I don't need to show my table because I only use one column of datetime

```
data_vencimento datetime
```

If I have 2018-10-29 , 2018-10-29, 2018-09-29. It should be sorted as

```
10/2018
09/2018
```

notice that the repeated date is "removed" and a sorted list of  formatted date was generated

here is my attempt. It is generating repeated results.

```
select distinct(data_vencimento),  date_format( data_vencimento,'%m/%Y' ) as data from (
select data_vencimento from custo_extra_movimento where id_admin
   union
select data_vencimento as data from custo_fixo_movimento where id_admin
   union
select data_vencimento as data from custo_variavel_movimento where id_admin) as tbl order by data_vencimento desc ;
```

Comment: I'm confused.  Does your result set have one column or two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `Distinct` is not a function; so you do not need to use parentheses with Distinct.
- Nevertheless, you need a Distinct combination of Month and Year, so you can use `Group By` instead, alongwith date functions like `Month()` and `Year()`.
- Also, in your `Union` queries, defining `data` alias for second and third Select query will not serve any purpose. MySQL would consider the first Select query column name only.

Do the following instead:

```
SELECT 
  YEAR(tbl.data_vencimento) AS year_data, 
  MONTH(tbl.data_vencimento) AS month_data, 
  DATE_FORMAT( MAX(tbl.data_vencimento),'%m/%Y' ) AS data 
FROM (
      select data_vencimento from custo_extra_movimento where id_admin
      union
      select data_vencimento from custo_fixo_movimento where id_admin
      union
      select data_vencimento from custo_variavel_movimento where id_admin
     ) AS tbl 
GROUP BY year_data, month_data 
ORDER BY year_data DESC, month_data DESC
```

Comment: I got " Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in SELECT list, references column 'tbl.data_vencimento' which is not in SELECT list; this is incompatible with DISTINCT"

Comment: I forgot to say I want a distinct list of month/year :(. Days are making the months repeat.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is sufficient:

```
select date_format(data_vencimento, '%m/%Y') as data from custo_extra_movimento where id_admin
union  -- on purpose to remove duplicates
select date_format(data_vencimento, '%m/%Y') as data from custo_fixo_movimento where id_admin
union  -- on purpose to remove duplicates
select date_format(data_vencimento, '%m/%Y') as data from custo_variavel_movimento where id_admin
order by data desc;
```

To be honest, I am a little unclear on the logic for the ordering, so that might be off.